# Cannot connect to postgresql user does exist database not how?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I installed Postgres-server and Postgres-desktop and opening PGAdmin which  I get an error:
The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted:

Then I tried to connect to postgres to see if it is running so I entered psql on the command line:

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  database "cal" does not exist
```

Then I created the user cal but the error remains so does it not create a database if you create a user?

Then I tried sudo psql:

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

Then I tried to create the user root using:

```
 sudo -u postgres createuser root
```

and I got:

```
could not change directory to "/home/cal": Permission denied
Password: 
createuser: error: creation of new role failed: ERROR:  role "root" already exists
```

So this is all a bit confusing. How are you then supposed to use the software if you cannot log in, cannot start pgadmin, cannot log in as root? On one line it says role does not exist but then when you want to create the role it tells you it already exists?

I added the database cal and I can connect to postgres typing psql and so that issue is solved. I still cannot use pgadmin which what I am really after. Here is the pgadmin runtime environment dump:

```
pgAdmin Runtime Environment
--------------------------------------------------------
Python Path: "/usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3"
Runtime Config File: "/home/cal/.config/pgadmin/runtime_config.json"
pgAdmin Config File: "/usr/pgadmin4/web/config.py"
Webapp Path: "/usr/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py"
pgAdmin Command: "/usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3 -s /usr/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py"
Environment: 
  - QT_SCALE_FACTOR: 1
  - LANGUAGE: en_ZA:en
  - USER: cal
  - XDG_SEAT: seat0
  - XDG_SESSION_TYPE: x11
  - COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE: mint
  - SHLVL: 0
  - HOME: /home/cal
  - DESKTOP_SESSION: mate
  - GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE: /home/cal/Desktop/pgadmin4.desktop
  - GTK_MODULES: gail:atk-bridge
  - XDG_SEAT_PATH: /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
  - DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS: unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
  - GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID: 3627
  - QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME: qt5ct
  - GTK_IM_MODULE: ibus
  - LOGNAME: cal
  - XDG_SESSION_CLASS: user
  - CLUTTER_BACKEND: x11
  - XDG_SESSION_ID: c2
  - GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING: 0
  - INSIDE_CAJA_PYTHON: 
  - PATH: /home/cal/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
  - GDM_LANG: en_US
  - GTK3_MODULES: xapp-gtk3-module
  - SESSION_MANAGER: local/i5:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1487,unix/i5:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1487
  - XDG_SESSION_PATH: /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
  - XDG_RUNTIME_DIR: /run/user/1000
  - DISPLAY: :0
  - LANG: en_ZA.UTF-8
  - XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: MATE
  - XMODIFIERS: @im=ibus
  - XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP: mate
  - XAUTHORITY: /home/cal/.Xauthority
  - XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR: /var/lib/lightdm-data/cal
  - SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
  - SHELL: /bin/bash
  - QT_ACCESSIBILITY: 1
  - GDMSESSION: mate
  - GPG_AGENT_INFO: /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
  - QT_IM_MODULE: ibus
  - XDG_VTNR: 7
  - PWD: /home/cal
  - XDG_CONFIG_DIRS: /etc/xdg/xdg-mate:/etc/xdg
  - CLUTTER_IM_MODULE: ibus
  - XDG_DATA_DIRS: /usr/share/mate:/home/cal/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share
  - MATE_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID: this-is-deprecated
  - QT_FONT_DPI: 96
  - GDK_BACKEND: x11
  - NO_AT_BRIDGE: 1
  - PGADMIN_INT_PORT: 44621
  - PGADMIN_INT_KEY: a29d2232-f512-48f4-b84c-2e1ccaaf7208
  - PGADMIN_SERVER_MODE: OFF
--------------------------------------------------------

Total spawn time to start the pgAdmin4 server: 0.005 Sec
Failed to launch pgAdmin4. Error:
Error: spawn /usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3 ENOENT
```

Comment: So the database server is running, otherwise you couldn't get that error message.  As the message says, the database doesn't exist.  Either create the database 'cal' (not the user 'cal', which apparently already exists), or connect to a different database--but neither of those will fix the pgAdmin4 issue.

Comment: Use all the commands needed, like the database you like to connect and the database user you like to use for this connection. If you don't tell psql what to use, it will use some defaults based on your system. And in most cases that won't work. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html

Comment: Take a step back.  What is your OS?  How did you install the stuff?  From what repository?  What did you do after installing it?

Comment: I am running Linux Mint 21.1 and I installed Postgres 14 using the package manager. I installed pgadmin4-server and pgadmin4-desktop using the deb files I got from the postgres repo. I created a database for me 'cal' and one for root. I changed the password of postgres and root and cal to be the same. I made cal a superuser and I changed the pg_hba.conf to have the line: local   all            username    to be local  all cal md5 and now when I try to log into psql I get an error: failed: FATAL:  role "cal" is not permitted to log in yet I am superuser and I restarted postgres every time

Comment: You say you created user `cal`, then tried to connect, but got an error message that *database* `cal` does not exist. Well, then specify an existing database name! `psql -U cal -d databasename`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
su postgres
psql
```

And which linux distribution are you using ? Did you check the status of postgresql ? On some distro you need to start and enable it before first use.

Comment: Yes I have tried that and it works but I cannot change to user postgres every time why can it not work with my own username and/or root? But the real issue is making pgadmin work because I need that

Comment: You need to configure the pg_hba.conf file for the user you want to connect with, as a "peer" connection. The "pg_hba.conf" file is in your postgresql installation directory (by default on debian it is in "/etc/postgresql/13/main/" for postgresql 13). For example for a linux user you add the following line after the line for postgres user :

`local   all            username                                peer`

You can switch "all" by a specific database name

Comment: Honestly it makes no sense. I changed cal to be a superuser and I change the file like you mentioned and I get this error trying to use psql: failed: FATAL:  role "cal" is not permitted to log in

Comment: Did you restart postgresql after making the changes ? If you want more understanding on the subject, you should read the official documentation : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html